# What will happen if i delete /dev folder

Tags: android

What will happen if I delete the `/dev` folder?

I have a rooted android tab and I want to delete that folder since that is a system folder, I dare not delete it until I get required info.

The destination is `/dev`

Comment: A tablet? have you considered asking this on http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/ask if not perhaps you could search there for information

Comment: _Why_ do you want to delete that folder?

Comment: Why would you delete `/dev`?  I voted to migrate this to Android.SE, but on second thought, it might be better to just close this as off-topic or unclear here, as I'm sure it would be closed there as well.  There's absolutely no reason one would ever delete a vital part of any UNIX-based operating system (hint: even devices are represented as "files" on UNIX/Linux - now guess what `/dev` is!).

Comment: This is pretty much the same as deleting the `system32` folder on Windows to "save space". At best you are severely maiming your system, at worst you are completely nuking it.  Why do people insist on deleting things when they have no idea what that thing does? Often these things are there for a reason, first find out that reason ***then*** decide that you want to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

If you somehow manage to do that you will break the system.

See also: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/sag/html/dev-fs.html

This page contains information on what is held inside `/dev` which should explain why it is a bad idea to delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Bad things. Bad things will happen.

`/dev` contains a bunch of 'special files' that are essentially file abstractions to device hardware, driver interfaces etc. This is the standard way that parts of the OS can communicate to the hardware.  That's probably enough of a clue as to what might happen if somehow you were able to remove it.!

I wonder what you were trying to do?  The chances are there's another approach entirely.